# Unable to install nodejs on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

The command I ran was

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

and the error i got was

```
Error executing command, exiting
```

Comment: What is the question? A broader context? More logs?

Comment: We're not your personal debugging service.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what could be reason for the error as the information provided is sparse! But try installing node using `nvm` (Node Version Manager). It surely helps you when switching back and forth to older and newer versions.

https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Follow this link. This should work.